# What invokes this pattern matching rule?

Tags: gcc, makefile, pattern-matching

I have this Makefile which seems to be working, but I'm not sure how:

```
EXECUTABLE=hello
CC=gcc
OBJS = a.o

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

I know the top 3 lines are local defines, and when I type "Make" it will build the `all` target. Now from here I'm a little lost... I'm guessing:

1. Make sees the `$(EXECUTABLE)` label and jumps the that build command
2. it sees the `$(OBJS)` label and since `a.o` doesn't exist in the local directory it jumps to the pattern matching rule
3. Make finds `a.c` and runs the rule to generate `a.o`
4. Now Make returns to the `$(EXECUTABLE)` command and runs the combination of .o files to make the "hello" program

Questions:

1. Is my understanding of that flow correct?
2. Is the placement of the "label"s in this file relevant?
3. Is there some GNU documentation that I'm missing which confirms my suspicions of how this is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flow is basically correct. Make will build the first target listed in the file if you do not explicitly pass one on the command line. In most makefiles people will have `all` as the first target so like in your example you can just type `make` and it will automatically build the `all` target. What make does internally is build a list of dependencies that you are defining in your Makefile. `all` is dependent on `$(EXECUTABLE)` which is dependent on `$(OBJS)`. In order to satisfy the the creation of the `all` target it has to start at the bottom of that dependency list and work its way up. The make manual is actually very good if you want to take a look here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/ and notably to your specific question here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works

Comment: Thanks for the info. So that last link tells me the answer to #3 (which is the order of the labels **is** important) is that correct?

Comment: its only important for the case where you're not going to be providing a make goal such as the examples it gives "make all" "make clean" etc

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool to help answer to one part of my question at least, so I'll post it for the reference of myself and others:

It is possible to "debug" a Makefile via `$(warning <some string>)` calls.

So in my example I used it as such:

```
all: $(warning All before exe call) $(EXECUTABLE)
    $(warning All warning after call)

%.o : %.c
    $(warning before pattern)
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
    $(warning after pattern)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(warning before obj) $(OBJS)
    $(warning after obj)
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

And got the output showing me the flow:

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/C$ make
Makefile:6: All before exe call    // started at all
Makefile:14: before obj            // Jumped to EXECUTABLE label
Makefile:10: before pattern        // Jumped to pattern matching
Makefile:10: after pattern
gcc -o a.o -c a.c
Makefile:15: after obj             // back to EXECUTABLE label
Makefile:15: after build           // back to build command
gcc -o hello a.o
Makefile:7: All warning after call
```

Using this I discovered that I could do this:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(warning before obj) $(OBJS)
```

but not:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): 
    $(warning before obj) 
    $(OBJS)
```

Which makes sense since white space is important in Makefiles

Comment: $(info ) is another good make function for printing out info for instance $(info $(OBJS))

Comment: @ThePosey Thanks! I hadn't found anything on $info yet, does print generic strings too or just fields?

Comment: Note that placing `$(warning ...)` in the prerequisite list of a target does not do what you expect, because it is evaluated immediately when the makefile is read, not when the target is considered.

Comment: yeah $(info can print anything $(info HELLO THERE) or $(info $(OBJS))